# PostgreSQL: getting ordinal rank (row index? ) efficiently

Tags: postgresql, ranking, window-functions

You have a table like so:

```
id dollars dollars_rank points points_rank
1  20      1            35     1
2  18      2            30     3
3  10      3            33     2
```

I want a query that updates the table's rank columns (`dollars_rank` and `points_rank`) to set the rank for the given ID, which is just the row's index for that ID sorted by the relevant column in a descending order. How best to do this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: What about ties?  [Analytics](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SQL2008_windowing_queries)...

Comment: They would just have the same ranking.

Comment: Which version of postgres are you using?

Comment: @Wells: Then you want RANK or DENSE_RANK...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The window function [**`dense_rank()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) is what you need - or maybe `rank()`. The `UPDATE` could look like this:

```sql
UPDATE tbl
SET    dollars_rank = r.d_rnk
     , points_rank  = r.p_rnk
FROM  (
    SELECT id
         , dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY dollars DESC NULLS LAST) AS d_rnk
         , dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY points  DESC NULLS LAST) AS p_rnk
    FROM   tbl
    ) r
WHERE  tbl.id = r.id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1lPJBEdq)

`NULLS LAST` is only relevant if the involved columns can be `NULL`:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)