# PostgreSQL ranking query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424822/postgresql-getting-ordinal-rank-row-index-efficiently) but with the extra complication that I need to group by a common field

I have two tables, one for `competition_users` (for those competing in competitions) and another `competition_times` (to store their fastest times), but there are many different competitions in the same table.

I have created a new column `rank` in the `competition_times` table and now need to run an update for existing users to show their rank in their competition, I am trying to modify the solution given in the other SO answer without success

The tables are as follows...

**competition_users:**

`competition_user_id`, `competition_id`

**competition_times:**

`competition_time_id`, `competition_user_id`, `time_in_seconds`, `rank`

I am not sure if its possible to use `GROUP BY`? or if there is another way, so far I am trying something like this...

```
UPDATE competition_times
SET    rank = r.rnk
FROM (
    SELECT competition_time_id
         , dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY time_in_seconds ASC) AS rnk
    FROM competition_times, competition_users
    WHERE competition_times.competition_user_id = competition_users.competition_user_id
    GROUP BY competition_users.competition_id
    ) r
WHERE competition_times.competition_time_id = r.competition_time_id
```

Using postgreSQL 9

Thanks

Comment: Is there supposed to be a `rank` field on the `competition_users` table as well (which is what your SQL suggests)?

Comment: @tomtheguvnor no, sorry that was a copy & paste error, the rank is against the competition time (as this is a point-in-time snapshot)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my problem is that I can get the query tp provide a rank by competition...the example I provided doesnt work

Comment: @DaveB: "*doesn't work*" is not a valid PostgreSQL error message

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok but I knew the example SQL was a red herring, I just included it to show I had made some attempt at a solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `PARTITION BY` clause in the window function to keep the ranks separate between the competitions.

```
UPDATE competition_times
SET    
    rank = r.rnk
FROM (
    SELECT competition_time_id, dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY competition_id ORDER BY time_in_seconds ASC) AS rnk
    FROM competition_times
    INNER JOIN competition_users
      ON competition_times.competition_user_id = competition_users.competition_user_id
    ) r
WHERE competition_times.competition_time_id = r.competition_time_id
```

With the sample data below:

```
create table competition_users
(competition_user_id  int, competition_id   int);

create table competition_times
(competition_time_id int, competition_user_id int, time_in_seconds int, rank int);

insert into competition_users values 
(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,2),(6,2);

insert into competition_times values 
(1,1,10,null),
(2,2,20,null),
(3,3,15,null),
(4,4,15,null),
(5,5,10,null),
(6,6,7,null);
```

I get the results in competition_times of:

```
competition_time_id competition_user_id time_in_seconds rank
1                   1                   10              1
2                   2                   20              3
3                   3                   15              2
4                   4                   15              2
5                   5                   10              2
6                   6                    7              1
```

Where rows 1-4 are on one competition, and rows 5&6 are from another.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Gary that works a treat, I was not aware of Partition By clause